# AWS ELB and VPC Router interaction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have a pretty simple question that drives me nuts. I am trying to understand how VPC router (routing tables) and ELB interact with another. 
I read documentation and tried understanding it, but without success. My current understanding of a VPC is pretty much like this:

- Data passes the I-GW
- The I-GW uses the VPC router and its routing tables to forward the request/traffic to the ELB.
- The ELB is used to address e.g. EC2 instances

What I think I got from the internet:

- Data passes the I-GW
- The ELB is using listeners to determine incoming traffic (e.g. Port 80)
- ELB is forwarding the traffic to the instances.

Updated by adding diagram (sry, I did not earn the privileges to upload one directly). :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs3JL.png)

Comment: Internet Gateway allows your VPC to route traffic to internet. AWS ELB has a public dns name which is reachable from the internet. If your question is how can a user reach your ELB ? It is due to DNS resolution.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Comment: @ben5556 thank you for your response. I updated the question by adding a diagram. I hope it helps to understand what I mean. Generally speaking I am not sure if the VPC router is still used when working with an ELB.

Comment: VPC or subnet route tables are used for routing packets originating within the VPC/ subnet i.e. outbound traffic NOT inbound traffic. Traffic to AWS ELB DNS name is resolved to an IP address via DNS resolution + IP routing (https://www.metaswitch.com/knowledge-center/reference/what-is-ip-routing) to reach destination. Traffic from your VPC is routed using route tables. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ben5556: Again, thank you. In case of outbound traffic, e.g. the EC2 instance previously determined by the ELB is now sending the reponse back via the ELB using the route tables to "route" the traffic through the I-GW?

Comment: In case of a HTTP request, the response is sent back to the client via an open TCP connection on the server, typically the same one used to send the request. Whether it takes the same path depends on the configuration of the network and I am not entirely sure how it happens within AWS network. In most cases I think it would take the same path within AWS network.

Comment: @ben5556: I will do some research on the response path. Post your comment "VPC or subnet route tables..." as the answer. :) If possible also provide the link and section, where you found the answer "just outbound traffic". ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPC or subnet route tables are used for routing packets originating within the VPC/ subnet i.e. outbound traffic NOT inbound traffic. Traffic to AWS ELB DNS name is resolved to an IP address via DNS resolution + IP routing ([IP routing](https://www.metaswitch.com/knowledge-center/reference/what-is-ip-routing)) to reach destination. Traffic from your VPC is routed using route tables. Hope this helps